# (Different Approach) [EDITED: Please Review] An at most countable union of at most countable sets is at most countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question Re-phrased:

---

I'm having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around this problem. While I've looked through similar posts, It's difficult understanding the maths because I currently have another approach stuck in my head. Is this valid?

Question:
Prove that an at most countable union of at most countable sets is at most countable.

Proof:
Let **F = {A1, A2, ... , Ak, ...}** be an at most countable family of sets where each **$A_k \in$ F** is also at most countable for **$k \in N$**. Define **S = $ \bigcup_{A \in F}A_k $**.

If every **$A_k \in F $** is finite, then there exists a bijective **$g_k: A_k \rightarrow J_{n_k}$**  for every A $\in$ F. Therefore, for some m $\in$ N, S = $J_m$ such that **$m\le\sum_{k=1}^x(n_i) $**. Hence, S is finite and at most countable. However, if at least one $A_k \in F$ exists such that this $A_k$~N ($A_k$ is countable), then S = N because $J_n \subset$ N for all n $\in$ N. Hence, S is countable.

Therefore, S must be at most countable.

---

But this only works if F is finite. Need to rethink this.

Comment: What is the [axiom-of-choice] tag doing here?

Comment: your claim that "... one may consider the largest set $A_{max}$..." is incorrect. There need not be a maximal set in any sense or form.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a proof. And had I been grading it, I'd have given it no points.

1. At most countable includes the infinite case. All you did in your proof is to handle the case all the sets are finite.
2. Even if there is a maximal index in $F$, what difference does it make? You're just point out that you are going to assume there is one, even if there isn't, but then you don't use it again. As Ittay points out, this is a false statement, but you also don't use it. So why add it to the proof?
3. You haven't proved anything, you merely stated that "since those sets are all finite, their union has to be countable", *but that's exactly the statement you want to prove!*

   Instead you need to show that there exists some injection from $S$ into a set that you know is countable. For example $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb{N\times N}$.
4. The assumption that all sets are equipotent to a subset of $\Bbb N$, therefore their union is countable is false. Consider $\{\{x\}\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$, then each set in this family is equipotent with a subset of $\Bbb N$, but their union is not.

Comment: Did I just use bad notation with the $A_{max}$ and not explain how my statements agree with what you're stating? 1) it includes the infinite case if at least one $A_k \in F$ exists such that A~N. 2&3) If the sets are all finite, then there exists a function $g_k: A_k \rightarrow J_n$ for some n $\in$ N for every $A_k$. Then the union of every $A$ is $J_{n_{max}}$ because {1} $\subset$ {1,2} $\subset$ ... $\subset$ {1,2,...,$n_{max}$}. 4) Yes, but every $A_k$ IS confined to a subset of N. No?

Comment: Regardless, thank you for the response. I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Let $i_k:\mathbb{N} \to A_k$ be a surjection.

Define $W_n = \cup_{k=1}^n i_k(\{ 1,...,n-k+1\})$. Note the $W_n$ are nested,  finite and $\cup_{n=1}^\infty W_n = \cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$.

Let $\Delta_n = W_n \setminus \cup_{k=1}^{n-1} W_k$. By renumbering if necessary, we may assume that all the $\Delta_n$ are non-empty.

Let $d_k = |\Delta_k|$ and
$j_k:\{1,...,d_k\} \to \Delta_k$ be a bijection.

Now let $\delta_n = \min \{ m | n \le d_1+\cdots+d_m \}$ and define the bijection
$\phi:\mathbb{N} \to \cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ by
$\phi_n = \begin{cases} j_1(n), & \delta_n = 1 \\j_{\delta_n}(n-(d_1+\cdots+d_{\delta_n-1})) ,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.